# How can I pass a vector variable to a function?

Tags: c++, vector, arguments

How can we pass `vector` variables to a function? I have a `vector` of `char*` and a function which will take a `char *` as an argument. How can I pass the `vector` variable to this function?

Comment: first one i.e. std::vactor<char*> v;

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function taking a char* argument, then you can only pass one of the char* in the vector.  For example:

```
std::vector<char*> v;
char buf[] = "hello world";
v.push_back(buf);
the_function(v[0]);
```

If you want to call the function on each member in the vector, just loop:

```
for (std::vector<char*>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    the_function(*i);
```

EDIT: based on your comment below, you actually want to write a function that accepts the vector as an argument... try:

```
void the_function(const std::vector<char*>& v)
{
    // can access v in here, e.g. to print...
    std::cout << "[ (" << v.size() << ") ";
    for (std::vector<char*>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
         std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << " ]";
}
```

If you have an existing function that you want to call, and you don't want to change its argument list...

```
void TV_ttf_add_row(const char*, const char*, const void*);
```

...then, say you know the vector will have enough elements:

```
assert(v.size() >= 3); // optional check...
TV_ttf_add_row(v[0], v[1], v[2]);
```

or

```
if (v.size() >= 3)
    TV_ttf_add_row(v[0], v[1], v[2]);
```

or, if you want an exception thrown if there aren't enough elements in `v`, then...

```
try
{
    TV_ttf_add_row(v.at(0), v.at(1), v.at(2));
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "caught exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

(the try/catch block doesn't have to surround the single function call - just as long as the `v.at( )` calls are somewhere inside the `try` block or a function directly or indirectly called from inside the block).

Comment: Or `std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), the_function);`

Comment: @Chris: that's awesome in this specific case, but I think it's essential that beginners learn simple iteration first as it's much more widely applicable to the tasks they'll typically need to perform.

Comment: Thanks Tony for answer.error: cannot convert 'std::vector<char*, std::allocator<char*> >' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int TV_ttf_add_row(const char*, const char*, const void*)'

Comment: Thanks Tony for answer. BUT when im trying to pass this vector variable to function the_function(const char* ) e.g. v.push_back(va); and then the_function(v); it through an    error: cannot convert 'std::vector<char*, std::allocator<char*> >' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int TV_ttf_add_row(const char*, const char*, const void*)'

Comment: @Balaji: some further options given above... hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the vector elements using its index:

```
void f(char* s)
{
    // do something with s
}

std::vector<char*> char_vect;
size_t len = char_vect.size();
for (size_t i=0; i<len; ++i)
    f(char_vect[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass the contents of a std::vector to a function that takes a C array, you can take the address of the first element of the vector:

```
void someCfunc(char *);

std::vector<char *> somevec;
// set up the vector ... then:
someCfunc(&somevec[0]);
```

HOWEVER - be careful you don't get the C string convention mixed up here! A `std::vector` will not append a `'\0'` to the end of the string automatically; you must do that manually. If it's just a byte buffer, you'll need to pass the vector's size separately. And if you're receiving data back into the vector, the C function cannot expand the vector on its own, so it's up to you to ensure the vector is large enough beforehand.

Note also that this applies only to `std::vector` and not to other STL containers.